# How to get correct reference to label of custom counters?

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I need several custom counters in my document which need to be referenced throughout the text. I figured how to create custom counters which can be labeled and referenced. Example: If I show the 3rd definition located in subsection 1 of section 2, `\ref{bestdef}` is supposed to give me "2.1.3". Now my problem is that `\ref{bestdef}` just shows "2.1" and leaves out the custom counter of definitions (the link works though). What is it I am missing? See my minimal example attached.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,format=plain,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Custom Counter: Definition %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{mydefcounter}\setcounter{mydefcounter}{1}
\newcommand{\mydef}[1]{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{mydefcounter}\textbf{#1}\refstepcounter{mydefcounter}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
Definition \mydef{\label{nicedef}}: This is my first definition.

\subsection{Second Subsection}
Definition \mydef{\label{verynicedef}}: This is my second definition.

\section{Second Section}
\subsection{Third Subsection}
In Definition \ref{nicedef} we had seen that...

In Definition \ref{verynicedef} we had seen that...

Definition \mydef{\label{bestdef}}: This is my third definition.

In Definition \ref{bestdef} we see that...
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I think you don't have understood the `\label` and `\ref` mechanism really. I find the `\mydef` macro weird for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

In my point of view, there's no need to use such a counter at all with the conjunction of `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[subsection]` and the usage of proper labels and `cleveref` package.

First an explanation why the OP way fails:

`\label` needs a previous `\refstepcounter` call, which defines `\@currentlabel`, which is explicitly using `\themydefcounter` in this example here.

`\themydefcounter` is nothing but `\arabic{mydefcounter}` so this gets out of line at some point.

See the example at the end:

```
\documentclass{article}


\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[subsection]

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\begin{definition} \label{nicedef}

This is my first definition.
\end{definition}

\subsection{Second Subsection}
\begin{definition} \label{verynicedef}
  This is my second definition.
\end{definition}

\section{Second Section}
\subsection{Third Subsection}

In \Cref{nicedef} we had seen that...

In \Cref{verynicedef} we had seen that...

\begin{definition}\label{bestdef}

This is my third definition.
\end{definition}

In \Cref{bestdef} we see that...
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Now the 'wrong' and 'correct' usage:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{foo}
\setcounter{foo}{1}
\newcommand{\mydef}[1]{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{foo}\refstepcounter{foo}\textbf{#1}}


\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\subsection{foosubsection}


\makeatletter
A def: \mydef{\label{firstfoo}} 

But this is the connected \verb!\@currentlabel!: \@currentlabel

\ref{firstfoo}

Another def: \mydef{\label{secondfoo}} 

But this is the connected \verb!\@currentlabel!: \@currentlabel

\ref{secondfoo}

Now do it better: 

\renewcommand{\thefoo}{\thesubsection.\arabic{foo}}
\renewcommand{\mydef}[1]{\refstepcounter{foo}#1\textbf{\thefoo}}

A def: \mydef{\label{thirdfoo}} 

But this is the connected \verb!\@currentlabel!: \@currentlabel

\ref{thirdfoo}

Another def: \mydef{\label{fourthfoo}} 

But this is the connected \verb!\@currentlabel!: \@currentlabel

\ref{fourthfoo}


\makeatother


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `\label` and `\ref` is rather weird, and I didn't try to understand what is going wrong. Rearranging some of your definitions, however, makes everything work as expected:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,format=plain,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Custom Counter: Definition %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{mydefcounter}
\renewcommand{\themydefcounter}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{mydefcounter}}
\newcommand{\mydef}[1]{\refstepcounter{mydefcounter}\label{#1}\themydefcounter}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
Definition \mydef{nicedef}: This is my first definition.

\subsection{Second Subsection}
Definition \mydef{verynicedef}: This is my second definition.

\section{Second Section}
\subsection{Third Subsection}
In Definition \ref{nicedef} we had seen that...

In Definition \ref{verynicedef} we had seen that...

Definition \mydef{bestdef}: This is my third definition.

In Definition \ref{bestdef} we see that...
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]